# Inserting an image multiple times based on difference between 2 numbers. PHP

Tags: php, image, loops

working on a script, that calculates the difference between dates retrieved from an API. I want it to then drop in an image as many times as the difference.

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2012-04-04');
$d2 = new DateTime('2012-03-31');

$interval = $d1->diff($d2);
```

Ive tried to have a go with a for loop but with no success

```
for ($i = 0 $i <= $interval; $i++) 
{ 
  echo = "<img src=\"test.jpg"/";
}
```

can you guys see any problems?

Comment: Your echo command looks weird. The second internal quote mark isn't escaped, and there's no closing bracket. Is that an error?

Comment: Also, when something doesn't work, it's helpful to say exactly what did happen (or to show the text that PHP actually outputs). It makes it much easier for us to figure out what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find PHP's DateTime works better when you use the modify() method instead of normal arithmetic.
Assuming you want one image per day:

```
$d1 = new DateTime('2012-04-04');
$d2 = new DateTime('2012-03-31');    

while($d2 <= $d1)
{
     echo "<img src=\"test.jpg\">";
     $d2->modify("+1 day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<?php
$d1 = strtotime('2012-04-04');
$d2 = strtotime('2012-03-31');

$interval=($d1-$d2)/(3600*24);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $interval; $i++) 
{ 
  echo '<img src="test.jpg">';
}
?>
```