# Manipulating php array

Tags: php, arrays, echo, items

Hi guys i have an array that is populated with dates

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-04-04
    [1] => 2012-04-06
    [2] => 2012-04-06
    [3] => 2012-04-06
    [4] => 2012-04-06
    [5] => 2012-04-06
    [6] => 2012-04-06
    [7] => 2012-04-11
    [8] => 2012-04-12
    [9] => 2012-04-12
    [10] => 2012-04-13
    [11] => 2012-04-13
    [12] => 2012-04-13
    [13] => 2012-04-13
    [14] => 2012-04-13
    [15] => 2012-04-13
    [16] => 2012-04-13
)
```

How would I loop through the array and find the difference in days between items next to each other in array. For example i would want to echo out

difference between [0] and [1] is "2" days
difference between [1] and [2] is "0" days

:)

Managed to get some output from the top answer however i only want it to display if there is a difference in date.

No output from this if statement though - UPDATED -

```
$count = count($datestack);



for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($datestack[$i]);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($datestack[$i + 1]);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    if ($arr[$i] === $arr[$i+1]){
     echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to stick with your questions.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917611/inserting-an-image-multiple-times-based-on-difference-between-2-numbers-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918065/looping-json-document-loading-string-into-array-then-manipulating-the-document

Comment: apologies i thought it was a slightly different question as im struggling with the syntax of highlighting array items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Example:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-04-04');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2012-04-06');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

And you just need loop your array to do what you want.

```
$count = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count - 1; $i++) {
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($arr[$i]);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($arr[$i + 1]);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
}
```

Comment: What would the syntax be for array items instead of 2 separate variables?

Comment: Ive updated my question based on your answer i still need a little help :)

Comment: @user1064660 What about add `if ($arr[$i] === $arr[$i+1]) continue;` right after for loop.

Comment: updated my question i still get an output like "+2 days+0 days+0 days+0 days" though

Comment: @user1064660 Are your values strings?

Comment: Yeah. The calculation works as it recognizes the difference between the 2 numbers though. I just don't want to show anything when the date's arent different

Comment: Could you just check `$arr[$i] === $arr[$i+1]`'s result? `"2012-04-06" === "2012-04-06"` should return true unless they are not strings.

Comment: Return's true so i'm guessing they are strings

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
     foreach($input as $k=>$i){ if(empty($input[$k-1])) continue; echo "<br /> difference between [".($k-1)."] and [".$k."] is ".'"'.round(abs(strtotime($i)-strtotime($input[$k-1]))/(3600*24)).'"'." days "; };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $dates = array(
        '2012-04-04',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-06',
        '2012-04-11',
        '2012-04-12',
        '2012-04-12',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13',
        '2012-04-13'
   );

   array_walk($dates, function($item, $key) {
        static $previous = null;
        if ($previous != null) {
            $datetime1 = new DateTime($previous);
            $datetime2 = new DateTime($item);
            $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
            echo $interval->format('%R%a days') . "\n";
        } 
        $previous = $item;
   }); 

?>
```

Comment: I don't think my version of PHP supports that function, i receive a T_FUNCTION error. Is there anyway i can bypass it?

Comment: Sounds like you are not on PHP 5.3 so you can't pass in a lambda. You will need to extract the `function($item, $key)...` part into a standalone function `function processDate($item, $key)...`. Now, you can pass in 'processDate' as the second parameter to array_walk.